# Value in register keeps resetting to 0 every clock cycle

Tags: verilog, counter

I do not understand why the timer counter in this code does not work. At the end of every clock cycle the value resets to 0, so the output would look like this:

```
clock: 0  timer: 0
clock: 1  timer: 1
clock: 0  timer: 0
clock: 1  timer: 1
```

Code:

```
module controller(clock, reset, enable, lightN, lightS, lightE, lightW, NScolor, EWcolor);

input clock, reset, enable, lightN, lightS, lightE, lightW;
output NScolor, EWcolor;

wire clock, reset, enable, lightN, lightS, lightE, lightW;
reg NScolor, EWcolor;
reg timer;


always @ (posedge clock)
begin: COUNT
    $display("TIMER = %d", timer); 
    if (reset == 1) begin
    $display("Resetting!");
        NScolor<= 1;
        EWcolor<= 0;
        timer <= 0;
    end
    else if (enable == 1) begin
        timer <= timer + 1;
        if (timer == 7) begin
            switchLights;
        end
        else if (timer >= 10) begin
            timer <= 0;
            switchLights;
        end
    end
end

task switchLights;
begin
    if (NScolor == 0 && EWcolor == 2) begin
        NScolor<= 1;
        EWcolor<= 0;
    end
    else if (NScolor == 1) begin
        NScolor<= 2;
        EWcolor<= 0;
    end
    else if (NScolor == 2) begin
        NScolor<= 0;
        EWcolor<= 1;
    end

    if (EWcolor == 0 && NScolor == 2) begin
        EWcolor<= 1;
        NScolor<= 0;
    end
    else if (EWcolor == 1) begin
        EWcolor<= 2;
        NScolor<= 0;
    end
    else if (EWcolor == 2) begin
        EWcolor<= 0;
        NScolor<= 1;
    end
end
endtask

endmodule
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have declared timer as:

```
reg timer;
```

which is a single-bit register. Hence, it only assumes values 0 an 1 in your simulation.

You may declare it as a multi-bit register, or declare it as an integer variable (assuming this code is anyway for simulation-purposes only, not for synthesis).

Note that you also have other issues in your code. For instance you declare EWColor as a single bit, but still attempt to assign it to 2, and compare it against 2.

Comment: That was the problem. Sorry for the messy code, just a programmer given a hardware project for class. Yes it is just for simulation. Thank you.